# Watching for multiprocessing to finish

Tags: python, multiprocessing

The `poolDict` dictionary here is used to write some updates on the processes started with `multiprocessing` Pool(). The `while loop` is running at the background and it is watching for any updates happening with poolDict. As soon as the condition is met `len(poolDict)==3` while loop is stopped. 
The code below runs fine. But a real world program that utilizes the same approach outlined here introduces some strange behavior. The `while loop` for example doesn't want to stop running even after the condition is met. It takes at least 15 seconds for `while` loop to finally 'realize' that len(poolDict) is already equal to 3. It causes a noticeable time lag that needs to be fixed. Instead of `while` loop what else could be used as a replacement? What approach to take in order to make an update instant?

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
poolDict=mp.Manager().dict()

def myFunction(arg):
    print '\n\tprocessing arg', arg, '...'
    for i in range(arg+1):
        if i==arg:
            poolDict[arg]=True
            print '\n\t\t...processing completed for', arg

pool=mp.Pool(processes=2)
pool.map_async( myFunction, [15000001,15000002,15000003] )

status=True
while status:
    print status
    time.sleep(.2)
    if len(poolDict)==3:
        status=False
        print '...while loop was stopped'

print 'completed'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the return value of map_async?

```
result=pool.map_async(myFunction, ...)
result.wait()
```

Since the dictionary itself destroys the order of the values, I would in fact consider using imap_unordered to transport all the values, something like:

```
def myFunction(arg):
     # time consuming stuff...
     return arg, True

nonpooldict = dict(pool.imap_unordered(myFunction, data))
# Will collect results in a dictionary as they are calculated
```

Otherwise you may want to try a synchronization method such as SyncManager.Event. I'm not sure if there is a way to flush specific types of SyncManager changes like the dictionary.

Comment: If I am using `result=pool.map_async(myFunction, ...)
result.wait()` approach how do I get myFunction()'s returned values? Are they all stored in 'result' variable? How to retrieve the returned by myFunction() values?